# Create manual Tweet box to add on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I am new to PHP and I want to add a tweet box to my wordoress site like this : http://screencast.com/t/jdUw9LTXngOz

If anyone can tell me how to do this also how can I add it to my existing wordpress site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've asked google instead of you and have got some really interesting stuff:

Twitter feed without PHP: http://www.themelab.com/2010/05/18/custom-twitter-widget-tutorial/

Or real WordPress twitter widget from scratch: http://theme.fm/2011/06/tutorial-creating-a-twitter-widget-for-wordpress-91/

Or if you don't want to write your own plugin, use any availeble in [Plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=twitter%20widget)